# -bash: npm: command not found after using Node LTS installation package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have tried installing Node (and therefore also npm) using the current LTS installer package from their website, which all seemed to go ok. However, when I try using the npm command I get `-bash: npm: command not found`

As per answers elsewhere on this site I tried the installer again but fared no better. `/usr/local/bin` is in my $PATH and there is an npm listed in that directory which links to a file called npm-cli.js elsewhere, but when I `which npm` nothing comes up.

Do I have to add something else to my $PATH?